# PHP loop (for each day of a week and each hour)

Tags: php

I want to create a loop (the result will be inserted into javascript)

Syntax:

- The first number is the day (Monday - Friday/1 - 5)
- The second number is the hour (1 - 11)

**So this is finally what the loop should return:**

```
subject_1_1: $("#subject_1_1").val(),
subject_2_1: $("#subject_2_1").val(),
subject_3_1: $("#subject_3_1").val(),
subject_4_1: $("#subject_4_1").val(),
subject_5_1: $("#subject_5_1").val(),
subject_1_2: $("#subject_1_2").val(),
subject_2_2: $("#subject_2_2").val(),
subject_3_2: $("#subject_3_2").val(),
subject_4_2: $("#subject_4_2").val(),
subject_5_2: $("#subject_5_2").val(),
subject_1_3: $("#subject_1_3").val(),
```

until

```
subject_5_11: $("#subject_5_11").val()
```

The last element shouldn't have a comma.

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// first sets x = 1, then, while x isn't equal to 5 the code
// inside `{ ... }` is executed and x is added 1
for($x=1;$x<=5;$x++){
    // again, but this time with y, from 1 to 11.
    for($y=1;$y<=11;$y++){
        // So we end up here and we now this code is going to execute
        // elevent times for each x value, and a total of 5 x values.
        // thats (x = from 1 to 5) * (y = from 1 to 11).
        // This string is printed (`echo`) every time for each iteration.
        echo "subject_1_3: $(\"#subject_".$x."_".$y."\").val()".(!($x==5&&$y==11)?",":"")."\n";
    }
}
```

**Edited 1:** now removes last comma.

**Edited 2:** added comments, but read:

In the string being printed, I notice this code:

```
!($x==5&&$y==11)?",":""
```

That does the following:

```
if this is true ? this is executed : and if it is not, then this is executed
```

So, in pseudo:

```
(if not (x=5 and y = 11)) then (print comma) else (don't)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer please? It helps others more to have well-documented code they can learn from than having a code-only answer to their specific question.

Comment: This works but on the last row, I have a comma. How can I get rid of this last comma?

Comment: @WaiHaLee there, explained. Any questions will be glad to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in the JavaScript itself?

```
var obj, x, y;
obj = {}; // this will be the object your subject_X_Y properties belong to
for( x=1; x<=5; x++) {
    for( y=1; y<=11; y++) {
        obj['subject_'+x+'_'+y] = $('#subject_'+x+'_'+y).val();
    }
}
```